# How can I secure a private string (like an API key) within my .NET assembly that cannot be extracted through decompiling?

Tags: .net, obfuscation

One of the libraries I use requires that you pass it an API Key when you use it that is generated uniquely for your account, and must remain completely private and secure.

If I put the key into my application as `private const string API_KEY = "ABC";` then it might be possible for someone to decompile my code and view the key.

Is general .NET obfuscation (such as from a free obfuscation tool) sufficient to mask this, or is there a better way to try and stop snoopers getting hold of the original API Key?

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom section inside app.config file (good alternative). Populate it with your data (key) and then encrypt config file. Here is sample:

```
            //loading config file...
            config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("AvtoNetPublisher.exe");
            //getting specific section (in this case custom class)
            csp = (GmailSettingsProvider)config.GetSection("gsp");
            if (!csp.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
            {
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Configuration is not protected, proceed to enter configuration!", "Configuration is not protected", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                if (result != DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Configuration was interupted by user!");
                }
                csp.UserName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter user name", "UserName", csp.UserName, Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
                csp.Password = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter password", "Password", csp.Password, Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
                csp.ImapServer = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter ImapServer", "ImapServer", csp.ImapServer, Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
                csp.Port = Convert.ToInt16(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter int32 Port", "Port", csp.Port.ToString(), Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y));
                csp.EnableSSL = Convert.ToBoolean(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter bool EnableSSL", "EnableSSL", csp.EnableSSL.ToString(), Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y));
                csp.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");
                config.Save();
            }
```

This can be triggred on first app install or load.

Comment: Can I create an app.config with a protected section and distribute it with my finished product?

Comment: No because encryption is based on app.config and machine. This config will not work on other machine. You can use this code on product registration (afrer some web call), on install or some similar event to avoid your key be hardcoded anywhere installation package or assembly.

Comment: @Gregor So this isn't a good example of how to encrypt a static universal key to a third party component or API.

Comment: @slugster I agree with you, it's alternative solution. Using decompilers you can eventually get to the key saved inside the assembly. If you save the key to encrypted config then decompiler is for no use. Ultimative goal is to protect this key.